# Cannot install gns3-server on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: networking, apt, server, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install GNS3 server on my Ubuntu 20.10 'Groovy Gorilla' laptop but I'm stumbling upon a weird error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gns3-server : Depends: ubridge (>= 0.9.14) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Usually on packages you can run `sudo apt install -f`, but you have [broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/223267/212930), and there is a way to fix that.

Comment: Sorry, not `sudo apt install -f`, I meant for this scenario, `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! Unfortunately, the solution that you suggested did not resolve the issue :(

Comment: Is the package from this https://launchpad.net/~gns3/+archive/ubuntu/ppa   ppa?

Comment: Thank you, now it is working!